# iOS7/8 - Send Touch Events on Non Jailbroken iPhone/Pad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

Our requirement is to send touch events from remote service to non jailbroken iPhone or iPad.

After researching on this a bit, I understand that GSEvent can no longer (ie. iOS7+ doesnt support this method) be used to simulate touch event.

IOHID is other alternative which has been mentioned but again if I understand correctly, iOS 6.1 onwards , entitlement check has been added. IOHIDEventSystemCreate apparently compares the bundle identifier with "com.apple.springboard", if the comparison fails then the call silently fails.

I know that there are device lab providers who are doing this - one of them apparently interfaces with hardware but there is no indication that others are doing the same.

So my question is - is this possible? If yes any pointers as to how this can be achieved?